# How to dynamically add new records from one table into another in PowerPivot?

Tags: relational-database, powerpivot

I have two tables with a Many to One Cardinality between table1 and table2 using [CustCode]

```
Table1
+-----+--------+----------+--------+
|Order|CustCode| CustName | Sales$ |
+-----+--------+----------+--------+
|  1  |   1A   |  Jack    | 5,000  |
|  2  |   2A   |  Jill    | 20,000 |
|  3  |   3A   |  Bill    | 3,000  |
|  4  |   3B   |  Bill    | 2,700  |
+-----+--------+----------+--------+

Table2
+--------+--------+------------+
|CustCode|CustName| Type| Type2|
+--------+--------+-----+------+
|  1A    |  Jack  | OEM |   1  |
|  2A    |  Jill  | DIST|   1  |
|  3A    |  Bill  | DIST|   1  |
+--------+--------+-----+------+
```

Table1 is brought in using PowerQuery from a source which updates daily. Table 2 is a table in the existing workbook. Both are pulled into a "Data Model" in the same workbook using PowerPivot.

How can I dynamically take new records that appear in table1 (i.e., Order 4) with its new CustCode and place it into Table2 and place the same values for the Type and Type 2 fields because it's the same Customer (Bill) and his Type is a DIST and his Type2 is 1?